# Play Store Statistics Not Updating With My Apps Data

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app on Google Play Store, and its been there for more than five days. I am sure there are many downloads because I actually have about 10 reviews, however it still only says three downloads! How can that be? The Play Store statistics only show me the first two days from uploading the app. Is this normal? I have implemented Google Analytics in my app, but it still doesn't work correctly. Why is this?

Answer (score 16):

The Play Store Statistics can lag behind the Reviews and Analytics. The longest lag I've had is 3 days but I wouldn't worry about the delay for a couple more days. If there are still no statistics after a couple more days I would file a report using the help+support button in the top-right of the developer console then 'send feedback'.